# Add header at top for the spinner array in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
Using the code below and add it to the spinner. The ObjectList contains the list as below


        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
        hashSet.add("Select Object");
        hashSet.addAll(ObjectList);
        ObjectList.clear();
        ObjectList.addAll(hashSet);
```

ObjectList

```
{ "Paper", "Pen", "Pencil", "Ink", "Other"}
```

The expected output is

```
{ "Select Object", "Paper", "Pen", "Pencil", "Ink", "Other"}
```

Instead I'm getting

```
{ "Paper", "Pen", "Pencil", "Select Object", "Ink", "Other"}  OR
{ "Paper", "Select Object", "Pen", "Pencil", "Ink", "Other"}
```

depending on whether I place the code "hashSet.add("Select Object");" before or after .addAll

How to get the Select Object to the top?

Comment: `HashSet` is an unordered collection you can use `LinkedHashSet` to keep the Order . Why not just use a `ArrayList` instead

Comment: ObjectList is a ArrayList. Unable to make the changes required, saw that HashSet can be used as an intermediary.